# Custom on hover and ul/li elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new here, so please tell me if I formulated something wrongly, code or text-wise.

[This](https://pastebin.com/agFWruuw) is the code I'm currently using for my page. Yes, I know it's short and terrible, but I'm still learning HTML/CSS. If you run that on a page, you'll notice no hover events on the navbar buttons, and some fiddling with the logo will reveal that the actual navbar is a big bar. (width:100%?)

I was only wondering as to how I would go about creating an on hover that's only slightly there, something like this: (hovered on the left, not hovered on the right)
[Hover showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWwxY.png)

I don't necessarily need it using my current setup or it being exact, but I'd like an explanation as to how this would be done. (the site I took it from has fancy fade on the text turning blue and a slide animation on the bar from the bottom, but I don't expect I'll be able to do that)

I was also wondering how I could have the logo be on the same bar as the other li elements, and then center it off how long logo + li elements (the whole bar) would be. (as opposing to having the li elements centered and a logo off to the left.) Also, a thick, colored bar above the navbar, but not below, like a margin, and having the navbar be a little thicker as well, as  the picture above depicts fairly well.

Thank you for any assistance I can recieve!

Hyao

Comment: Are the `#` symbols in the css typos?

Comment: @hlfrmn it looks like OP was trying to comment those lines out.

Comment: Yep! It oddly worked, but I guess it's still an error/worked because it's an error.

Answer (score 1):

So for the hover color you can do something like:

```
li:hover {
    color: blue;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
```

To add more of the animation you might want to do:

```
    li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    li a:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

    li a:after {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 0px;
        height: 3px;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        background-color: blue;
        transition: width 0.5s linear;
    }

    li a:hover:after {
        width: 100%;
    }

    li img {
       padding: 14px 16px;
    }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GrxqcRjoMa7aWjHvnBhA

basically you are creating a psuedo element :after which has an animation on its width. When you hover over an li element the psuedo element will grow to 100% of the width looking like an expanding underline.

To make the image inline with the other elements remove your position: absolute style for the #logo

Comment: How would I go about excluding the img from the underline?

Comment: You could do something like `ul > li:not(:first-child))` or you could move the :hover and :after styles to all a tags (ie: `ul > li > a:hover {} ul > li > a:after {}`)

Comment: Right. I see what you mean and how it works, but where would I put this? As I said, I'm not terribly good at this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, these styles go in your CSS code. You could use an external one or write them in style tags (like you currently are doing) or write everything online.

Comment: I meant where do I put `ul > li:not(:first-child))` in the CSS